# Sending authentication with WebBrowser control and proxy

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I am using .net WebBrowser for web browsing in my application, as I know the control is base on IE therefore to set a proxy I was looking how to configure the IE proxy settings. Came up with pinvoke InternetSetOption with following code:

```
private void SetIESettings(string proxy)
{
    const int INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY = 38;
    const int INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY = 3;

    Struct_INTERNET_PROXY_INFO struct_IPI;

    struct_IPI.dwAccessType = INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY;
    struct_IPI.proxy = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(proxy);
    struct_IPI.proxyBypass = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi("local");

    IntPtr intptrStruct = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(struct_IPI));
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(struct_IPI, intptrStruct, true);
    InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY, intptrStruct, Marshal.SizeOf(struct_IPI));
}
```

Works like a charm, after setting the proxy the control goes through it. Something the proxy need credentials and before going through it a user name and pass need to be given. I tried to add additional header for the webBrowser.Navigate method like this:

```
var credentialStringValue = "user:password";
var credentialByteArray = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(credentialStringValue);
var credentialBase64String = Convert.ToBase64String(credentialByteArray);
var credentials = string.Format("Authorization: Basic {0}{1}", credentialBase64String, Environment.NewLine);
```

then calling the navigation

```
webBrowser.Navigate("http://google.com", "", null, credentials);
```

did not helped, still getting the authentication form. Also tried to add Proxy-Authorization header with same value, still nothing.

Also tried to set the user and pass at internet explorer options as following:

```
const int INTERNET_OPTION_USERNAME = 28;
const int INTERNET_OPTION_PASSWORD = 29;
var uesr = "user";
var pass = "password";
InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_USERNAME, uesr, uesr.Length + 1);
InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_PASSWORD, pass, pass.Length + 1);
```

Still not working, the security window keeps popping up.
Obviously I am doing something wrong, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Your direction is right. I met the issue when using IE comobject

> 0x800C000E

Following MS KB gives details why IE not supporting username and password in URL address. I tried to add the registry in the KB, solved my problem.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/834489/internet-explorer-does-not-support-user-names-and-passwords-in-web-sit

[image]

Create a registry,

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet
>   Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_HTTP_USERNAME_PASSWORD_DISABLE

Add a DWORD value "iexplore.exe" and data set to "0"

Regarding your case, I think you can simply create a value pointing to your app and set data to "0" just like "iexplore.exe" and use the following URL format.

> https://username:password@xxx.yyy.zzz/home